# Override certain Gnome shortcuts while using applications making use of the same shortcuts

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have custom shortcuts for opening the terminal, opening my browser, home folder etc. But at times, these shortcuts clash with default, unchangeable shortcuts of other applications I use. I was wondering if there is a setting using which the application shortcut takes precedence over the shortcut specified in Gnome when that combination is pressed while said application is in use.

For example, I use `Ctrl + t` for opening my terminal, but this is the same shortcut used for opening a new tab in Firefox. I would like to know if there is setting which can be tweaked so as to open a new tab by pressing `Ctrl + t`when I have Firefox open but open a terminal window otherwise.

Note: Gnome shell version is 40.5

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to do this in Gnome, but you can override keybindings per application with either https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail or https://github.com/joshgoebel/keyszer (both X11 only)